# How to find the derivative of $f(x)=(x^3-4x+6)\ln(x^4-6x^2+9)$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Find the derivative of the following: $$f(x)=(x^3-4x+6)\ln(x^4-6x^2+9)$$ Would I use the chain rule and product rule?
So far I have:

$$\begin{align}g(x)=x^3-4x+6
\\g'(x)=2x^2-4\end{align}$$

would $h(x)$ be $\ln(x^4-6x^2+9)$?
If so, how would I find $h'(x)$?

Comment: What are $g(x)$ and $h(x)$? You haven't defined them as far as I can see.

Comment: g(x)=x^3-4x+6, g'(x)=2x^2-4, is h(x)=ln(x^4-6x^2+9)?

Comment: In $g'(x)$ you have a mistake in the first summand: $2x^2$ should be $3x^2$. Find $h'(x)$ using the chain rule.

Answer (score 1):

Something to notice is that $$x^4 - 6x^2 + 9 = (x^2 - 3)^2$$ and consequently, $$f(x) = 2 (x^3 - 4x + 6) \log (x^2 - 3).$$  This makes differentiation slightly easier:  $$f'(x) = 2\left( (3x^2 - 4)\log(x^2 - 3) + \frac{x^3-4x+6}{x^2-3} \cdot 2x \right).$$

Comment: it is $\log(x^2-3)^2=2\log|x^2-3|$

Comment: thus your answer is wrong

Answer (score 0):

given $f(x)=(x^3-4*x+6)\ln(x^4-6x^2+9)$ we find by the product and chaine rule
$f'(x)=(3x^2-4)\ln(x^4-6x^2+9)+(x^3-4x+6)\frac{4x^3-12x}{x^4-6x^2+9}$
simplifying this in a few minutes
simplifying this i got
$f'(x)=\frac{4 x^4-16 x^2+3 x^4 \ln \left(x^4-6 x^2+9\right)-13 x^2 \ln \left(x^4-6
   x^2+9\right)+12 \ln \left(x^4-6 x^2+9\right)+24 x}{x^2-3}$

Comment: where did you get the log from?

Comment: the $log$ must be $\ln$ sorry

Comment: i have corrected it

Comment: Wouldn't the unsimplified version also be correct? because the problem doesn't ask for the simplified answer

Comment: yes the unsimplified term is also correct